# Why does my program say that inputs like a or r belong in the interval -1,1?

Tags: c++

Why if I input any letter does my code then say that it belongs in the interval -1, 1 instead of moving to the else clause and printing the error message?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x ;                     
    cout << "Enter a real number : " ;  
    cin >> x ;                     
    

    if ((x >= -1) && (x < 1)) {
        cout << "The nunber you have entered is valid and lies in the interval -1,1!" << endl;
    }
    else if ((x < -1) || (x >= 1)) {
        cout << "Unfortunetely the number you entered is valid but does not lie in the interval" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error you have not entered a valid real number!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what input do you enter?

Comment: Add a check like `if (!(cin >> x)) { std::cout << "Input failed!\n"; return 1; }`

Comment: You're not checking whether `cin >> x` failed. When it does fail, the value that `x` holds will be undefined.

Comment: @Brian FWIW, starting in C++11, `cin` will zero out the passed in variable if the input stream is in a bad state.

Answer (score 1):

A `double` read from user input is always either inside `(-1,1]` or not. There is no third option. When the user enters something that cannot be parsed as a `double` then `0` is assigned to `x`. If you want to check for failure on input you should check the state of the stream. You can do that for example via its [conversion to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) inside an `if`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x ;                     
    cout << "Enter a real number : " ;  
    if (cin >> x) {       // <--- if reading x succeded
        if ((x >= -1) && (x < 1)) {
            cout << "The nunber you have entered is valid and lies in the interval -1,1!" << endl;
        } else if ((x < -1) || (x >= 1)) {
            cout << "Unfortunetely the number you entered is valid but does not lie in the interval" << endl;
        } 
    } else {
        cout << "Error you have not entered a valid real number!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to read more afterwards you would have to reset the fail state of the stream before.

---

PS: Floating point numbers are not real numbers, they are all rational.

Comment: Thank you so much! Another follow up questions, with floating numbers, I don't understand why decimals like 0.1 and 0.01 have to be approximated which leads to errors in some programs?

Comment: @Spare_Definition234 numbers are stored in binary. Some reading material: https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf

Comment: @Spare_Definition234 Here is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: This is skirting on false. `A double is always either inside (-1,1] or not. There is no third option.`. This alone is untrue. By definition a NaN is neither inside (-1.1] nor is it not. Its in neither. However, as reading a double in via cin doesn't allow you to read NaNs (for whatever broken reason) then this answer works. But if you did `double x = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();` then this answer fails whereas the OP's original attempt (which has a third option to the if/else clause) works well.

Comment: @MikeVine you are absolutely right, only "But if you did `double x = ...` then this answer fails " is incorrect since C++11. `std::cin >> x` will either suceed or assign `0` (unless `std::cin` was already in a fail state before, then nothing happens).